# Prove $\int_a^bf(x+x_0)\cos{\alpha x}dx=\int_a^bf(x)\cos{(\alpha(x-x_0))dx}$

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $\int_a^bf(x+x_0)\cos{\alpha x}dx=\int_a^bf(x)\cos{(\alpha(x-x_0))dx}$.

To do this, I used the substitution $u=x+x_0$, and so $x=u-x_0$, and also $\frac{du}{dx}=1$. Is this enough to prove the result? Or is it wrong?

Comment: It is true only if $ x_0=0$

Comment: How can we prove it is only true for $x_0=0$?

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to change the integration bounds:

$\int_a^bf(x+x_0)\cos{\alpha x}dx=\int_{a+x_0}^{b + x_0}f(x)\cos{(\alpha(x-x_0))dx} \tag{1}$

Considering this, it is easy to give a counter-example to your equality if $x_0 \neq 0$.